# BASH script to match a word using REGEX

Tags: regex, bash, csv

I have a CSV being read into a script that has the phrases:

```
This port supports SSLv3/TLSv1.0. 
This port supports TLSv1.0/TLSv1.1/TLSv1.2. 
This port supports TLSv1.2.
```

What I'm looking to do is setup a REGEX variable on the word/number:  **TLSv1.0**
Then reference that variable in an IF/Then statement. The problem I'm
having is getting the regex to see the TLSv1.0. Could somebody help me
craft my BASH script to see TLSv1.0 when it's along a line that starts off with "This port supports"?

```
#!/bin/sh
REGEX="\TLSv1.0\"

cat filename.csv | awk -F"," '{gsub(/\"/,"",$4);print $5}' | sed s/\"//g | 
while IFS=" " read pluginoutput
do

if [[ "$pluginoutput" =~ $REGEX ]]; then
.
. rest of my code
.
```

You can see that I'm trying to set the regex in the variable, but it just isn't working. Obviously a typo or something. Does anybody have a regex suggestion?

Thanks,

Comment: What's with the literal quotes? You're telling the shell to look for `"`s **within** the string being searched, but they clearly don't appear..

Comment: Also, `#!/bin/sh` is POSIX sh, not bash. If you want bash features, use bash: `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Also, `cat filename | awk ...` is less efficient than either `awk ... <filename` or `awk ... filename`.

Comment: Also, you *probably* shouldn't be piping into a while loop. See [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: (Also, why are you using both a gsub inside `awk` *and* a separate `sed` expression after? And is there a reason you're using `awk` at all, instead of just letting `read` extract the column you want?)

Comment: Also, use lower-case names for your own variables -- upper-case names are used for variables with meaning to the OS and shell; using names with at least one lowercase character for your own variables means you can't overwrite builtin or meaningful ones by accident.

Comment: What is final output you want to extract?

Comment: It would also be helpful to provide representative data from the input CSV.

Comment: You have a syntax error. `REGEX="\TLSv1.0\"` should be `REGEX=\"TLSv1.0\"`

Comment: `REGEX="\TLSv1.0\"` is quoting the `T` and not the `"`, so you don't even have code that runs. Please put the *tiniest* effort into proofreading your code and/or questions.

Comment: There are many reasons to these other questions, but that isn't really the core of what I'm looking to have answered. I'm trying to determine the correct regex syntax within a variable so it finds the word TLSv1.0 within the document being processed.

Comment: `[[ $foo =~ $bar ]]` is completely correct syntax. The problem here, as previously mentioned, is that your `$bar` doesn't contain what you think it does: It has **literal quotes** not found in the data you're searching for, so it will never match.

Comment: Which is to say: The item you insist you're trying to determine? You were already told its cause, in the very first comment.

Comment: BTW, when you're trying to look for a literal string, `[[ $line = *"$substring"* ]]` might be an easier way to do it, since the substring doesn't need to be a valid regex in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of things wrong here. To pick some key ones:

- `#!/bin/sh` specifies that you want your script to be interpreted with a POSIX-compliant interpreter, but doesn't specify which one. Many of these, like `ash` or `dash`, don't have `[[ ]]`, `=~`, or other extensions which your code depends on. Use `#!/bin/bash` instead.
- In `REGEX="\TLSv1.0\"`, the `"`s are **data**, not syntax. This means that they're part of the content being searched for when you do `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]`. By contrast, `regex=TLSv1.0`, `regex="TLSv1.0"` or `regex='TLSv1.0'` will all have the identical effect, of assigning `TLSv1.0` as the content of the `regex` variable.

  That said, as a point on regex syntax, you probably want `regex='TLSv1[.]0'` -- that way it will only match a `.`, as opposed to treating the dot as a match-any-character wildcard (as it is in regular-expression syntax).

Personally, I might do something more like the following (if I had a reason to do the parsing in bash rather than to let a single `egrep` call process all your input):

```
#!/bin/bash
regex='(^|,)"?This port supports .*TLSv1[.]0.*[.]"?($|,)'
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ $regex ]] && echo "Found TLSv1.0 support"
done
```